# Reverse print linked list in C++

Tags: c++, reverse

I would like to implement linked list. I wrote an insert list method, print method but have problems with reverse printing. The main problem is the reverse printing prints a normal list, not reversed:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node
{
    int value;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct List
{
    struct Node *first, *last;
};

Node* node(int v)
{
    Node *newNode = new Node();
    newNode->value = v;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

List*  list()
{
    List *newList = new List();
    newList->first = NULL;
    newList->last = NULL;
    return newList;
}

List*  insert(List* s, Node* n)
{
    if (s->last == NULL)
    {
        n->next = s->last;
        s->last = n;
        s->first = n;
        return s;
    }

    s->last->next = n;
    s->last = s->last->next;
    return s;
}

void  print(List* s)
{
    Node *tmp = s->first;
    while(tmp)
    {
        std::cout << tmp->value << ' ';
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

void reverse_print(List* s)
{
    if(s->first == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << '\n';
        return;
    }

    else
    {
        std::cout << s->first->value << ' ';
        s->first = s->first->next;
        reverse_print(s);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    List *myList2;
    myList2 = list();

    myList2 = insert(myList2, node(3));
    myList2 = insert(myList2, node(5));
    myList2 = insert(myList2, node(7));
    myList2 = insert(myList2, node(9));
    myList2 = insert(myList2, node(5));
    myList2 = insert(myList2, node(34));
    myList2 = insert(myList2, node(67));

    print(myList2);

    reverse_print(myList2);
}
```

Comment: I guess you should `cout` **after** calling `reverse_print` again.

Comment: You seem to be modifying your linked list in your `reverse_print()` function instead of using a local variable like in your `print()` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You shouldn't modify the list that you're printing.
2. You should recursively print "the rest of the list" first.

The best way is to have a separate function for printing nodes:

```
void reverse_print(Node* n)
{
    if (n != NULL)
    {
        reverse_print(n->next);
        std::cout << n->value << ' ';
    }
}

void reverse_print(List* s)
{
    reverse_print(s->first);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
else
    {
        std::cout << s->first->value << ' ';
        s->first = s->first->next;
        reverse_print(s);
    }
```

to

```
else
    {
        reverse_print(s);
        s->first = s->first->next;
        std::cout << s->first->value << ' ';   
    }
```

should help you use the recursion effectively.

Comment: It gives segmentation fault

Comment: @Brian Because you have to check if `s->first->next` isn't `nullptr` again.

Comment: @LogicStuff, I tried: http://pastie.org/private/kbfx1lnxj5dcbuibj8781g, it just gives segmentation fault anyway